# New version Kivy download

Tags: python, kivy

I just downloaded Kivy and it is on my desktop; however, it doesn't open when i click on it. What might be the cause of this annoying problem. The application has 232 MB which tells me it has all the appropriate documents in it, but for some reason, it just doesn't open.

```
LLama32$ python -c "import kivy" 

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named kivy
```

Comment: X Yosemite Versioin 10.10.5

Comment: Did you follow the [installation instructions](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-osx.html)?

Comment: Yes I did followed "Using The Kivy.app", and now I am trying the pip.

Comment: it seem like now my terminal doesn't recognize pip install -I Cython==0.23.

Comment: Please read the instructions again, an move the app to the right place and create the symlink, and finally use `kivy` rather than `python` when wanting to use kivy. The pip installation method is completely separate from your original question.

Comment: ok thank, i will see it again.

Answer (score 1):

Wow at least I have figured out my own problem, and hopefully other noobs like me will benefit from this hour long tedious research. 
So, it turned out that Kivy actually works using Cython. Unfortunately, Cython requires a C compiler on my computer to be able to function. Since I have no C compiler, (specially since I deleted Xcode from my computer as it occupies 4GB memory) I have no means to compile a C program. Now, this problem is simply resolved after downloading any GNU Compiler Collection, in my case, I re-downloaded Xcode.